# Динамическая подстановка дат

Tags: javascript

есть такой счетчик:

```js
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date('Jun 30, 2020 00:00:00').getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {    

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = countDown - now;

      document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
    }, second)
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><span id="days"></span>days</li>
    <li><span id="hours"></span>Hours</li>
    <li><span id="minutes"></span>Minutes</li>
    <li><span id="seconds"></span>Seconds</li>
  </ul>
```

Подскажите, как автоматически, подставлять другую дату, когда счетчик обнулится?

То есть, на данном примере счетчик работает до 30 июня, после этого нужно поставить дату 30 сентября, потом 31 декабря, потом 31 марта, потом снова 30 июня и все заново

Answer (score 0):

Нужно определить какой сейчас месяц - это можно получить с помощью встроенного метода getMonth, исходя из этого уже подставлять нужную дату в счетчик. Следует учесть, что метод getMonth возвращает месяц в числовом формате начинаю с 0 (0 соответствует Январю)
Должно получится что-то наподобие этого:

```
let currentDate = new Date();
let currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
let timerDate;
if(currentMonth >= 3 && currentMonth < 6) {
  timerDate = 'Jun 30, 2020 00:00:00';
} else if(currentMonth > 6 && currentMonth < 9) {
  timerDate = 'Sep 30, 2020 00:00:00';
}
//...Остальные условия

let countDown = new Date(timerDate).getTime(),
//далее ваш основной код
```